# Can't download jar files using maven

Tags: maven

I've been using Maven for few years now, installing it on different machines and OS's and never had problem with it. Ten days ago i installed in on new Windows 7 machine and since than
i can't find the reason why it can't download jar file's from remote repo's. 
I am able to download jar file by typing URL in browser but when i run mvn install in console it start to download the jar, wait some time and then i am getting error message:

```
"...Could not transfer artifact org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:5.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
GET request of: org/primefaces/primefaces/5.0/primefaces-5.0.jar from central failed: 
Read timed out ... java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out".
```

I read all articles here, tried everything but without success.
Can anyone help?

Comment: maybe you need to set Maven proxy setting

Comment: I am not in company but private network.

Comment: Java permissions? Are other jars downloaded properly from central?

Comment: What java permission, what do you mean with that? I am trying to download primefaces lib only.

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces artefacts are not in Maven Central. You need to setup a supplemental repository to get those artifacts. I would suggest to start using a repository manager.

Comment: You are right regarding this, but i still have the same problem now with maven plugin, definitely something is wrong.

Comment: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1

Comment: clean your local repository and start the build from scratch on command line. Furthermore start using a repository manager.

Comment: I already did that few times without success, Do you mean using proxy like Sonatype Nexus? If yes, why should i use this if i am working alone?